# PostgreSQL function returning result set from nested queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have to write a PL/pgSQL stored procedure which has two inputs.
The first input should go into a select which returns a set of timestamps.

With these returned timestamps I intend to loop over a second select, which takes the second input of the function and returns a single row I have to collect in the iteration of the loop. I then assemble the output of the second select and return that as a result set.

```
FUNCTION (Input A B)
SELECT FROM T1 WHERE X = A INTO RS1.
LOOP VAL OVER RS1
   Select FROM T2 WHERE Y = B AND Z = VAL INTO RS2
END LOOP
RETURN ASSEMBLED RS2
```

Can somebody point me to a working skeleton on which I can work on, btw. what are the relevant parts I need from the documentation? I think I need:

- `RETURNS TABLE () AS` to declare the result set
- A `CURSOR` to loop over the second query, using the results of the first query

Comment: Why would you do this in a function when you can readily do it with a simple query using `join`?

Comment: Well the problem is that one select uses a <= in the when clause, which prevents me from using an IN. I do not how to do that otherwise

Comment: `JOIN` is not really related to `IN` -- you can read more [about the concept here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) instead of trying to iterate explicitly over rows using pgpsql code :

```
with T1_vals as (
  select val from T1 where X = A
), T2_vals as (
  select T2.val from T2, T1_vals where T2.Z = T1_vals.val and T2.Y = B
) select val from T2_vals;
```

As a general rule : be careful when you're tempted to iterate explicitly over values, as SQL offers generally simplier solutions with much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor, a nested function call or a loop.
You don't need a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), either.

Use a very basic query with a [`JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t2.z = t1.val 
WHERE  t1.x = _input_a
AND    t2.y = _input_b;
```

Set-based solutions are typically superior to a procedural approach in SQL. It's a rare occasion that looping is the best solution.